# zombie.js how do i select from a dropdown

Tags: forms, browser-automation, zombie.js

I have a blank page with a single select box which contains IP address' as values and i want to select a single value using zombine.js one of them.

```
this.browser.fill('select', '223.255.252.246');
```

This fails ^

but this succeeds:

```
this.browser.assert.element('select')
```

What am i missing? Is it not "fill" ?

Here is my test

```
// force the test environment to 'test'
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
// get the application server module
var app = require('../../app');
var http = require('http');
var Browser = require('zombie');
var assert = require('assert');

describe('contact page', function() {
  before(function(done) {
    this.server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000);// initialize the browser using the same port as the test application
    this.browser = new Browser({ site: 'http://localhost:3000' });
    this.browser.visit('/', done);
  });

  it('should load the homepage successfully', function(){
    assert.ok(this.browser.success);
  });

  it('shows a dropdown', function(){
    this.browser.assert.element('select')
  });

  it('selects china, and clicks "start"', function(){
    this.browser.fill('select', '223.255.252.246');
  });
  // ...

  after(function(done) {
    this.server.close(done);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

the answer is to use "select" e.g.:

```
this.browser.select('select', '223.255.252.246');
```